# PHP code to create folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

my project needs folder to be created whenever user registers using userid  inside upload folder so i'm using 
below lines but its not creating any new folder inside upload folder with userid

```
       $userid = $this->db->insert_id();
       $path   = './upload/'.$userid;
       if(!is_dir($path)) //create the folder if it's not already exists
       {
          mkdir($path,0755,TRUE);
       }
```

PS:  i am using wamp server and ci..

thanks

Comment: you need to check upload directory is writable or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this code

```
chmod('./upload/', 0777);
$path   = './upload/'.$userid;
if (!is_dir($path)) { //create the folder if it's not already exists
    mkdir($path, 0755, TRUE);
}
```

**upload dir path for CI**

[image]

Comment: i tried still not creating...upload folder must be within www folder rite?

Comment: upload folder should be where you have install CI, please check image i have added

Comment: so its in right path but still folder is not getting created

Answer (score 1):

```
$path   = './upload/'.$userid;
```

You should use a full path to create a directory and also the upload folder should have the right permissions to create dir's and files in it.

Comment: upload folder must be within www folder rite?